# Why we need to use async when get data from server?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to Flutter, I'm trying fetch data from the internet. I don't understand why this functions should be asynchronous?

Comment: Hello Mydev, what research have you done yourself already? Also, what's your plan on how to learn Flutter? Are you going to ask every question here?

Comment: I searched but explain not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous execution is a way to prevent the app (thread) to be blocked until the response from the server arrives, which can be seconds or even minutes and would be unacceptable for most apps, especially on mobile devices.

Dart by default runs a single thread (additional threads can be started using isolates) and is event driven. Async execution registers an event handler for the case that the response from the server arrives (according to your example).

`async`/`await` is an easy way to ensure code runs in the correct order - after a specific event happened.

This allows to run other code (event handlers) while one thread of execution is waiting for some event.

Other systems run multiple threads where threads waiting for responses are halted. Dart runs a single thread, but avoids blocking the thread by using async execution with an event queue.